# How to update and insert into databse using PHP when array in Javascript is updated?

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql, d3.js

I have a program that gets data from a database, and then graphs it using d3 and javascript. I have a couple of methods that update and insert data into the local arrays in javascript, but I need to update and insert in the database too. How would I do this? I am using PSQL for database.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php

   // attempt a connection
 $dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=data user=postgres");
 if (!$dbh) {
     die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
 }       

 // execute query
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM dataset";
 $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
 if (!$result) {
     die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
 }       


 $arr = pg_fetch_all_columns($result, 1);


 // free memory
 pg_free_result($result);       

 // close connection
 pg_close($dbh);

?>
```

And here's the methods I am talking about, the clickEvent prompts for input when a bar is clicked, and updates the length of the bar.

```
function clickEvent(d, i) {
    var op = prompt("Please enter the value", d);
    data[i] = parseInt(op, 10);
    render();

};
```

This method prompts for input when a "Add Data" is clicked, and adds a new bar.

```
d3.select("button").on("click", function(d, i) {
    var op = prompt("Please enter the value", "");
    var newData = parseInt(op, 10);
    if (!isNaN(newData)) {
      data.push(newData);
      render();
    }
});
```

Here's a [jfiddle for the javascript code](http://jsfiddle.net/NkkDC/7/) to see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you can pass the number to a script defined in "url" that will save the value to the database.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {barLength : newData},
  dataType: "html"
});
```

Comment: If the methods and javascript is in the same file as the php code, let's say "data.php", would I just set url to "data.php"?

Comment: You could do it in the same file, just check if $_POST[newData] is set, but I would prefer to break it out to its own file so the server does not process the entire page again and it's easier to manage.